# ModelForm validating data for new instance even after passing instance in form

Tags: django

I am creating view for edit data. I am using same model form and html script to create and edit data. In create view I am passing instance in form but form.is_valid is validating data fro new instance.

**models.py**

```
class Van(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vans')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    number_plate = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    commercial_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**forms.py**

```
class VanForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Van
        fields = ('commercial_name', 'number_plate', )

        def clean_number_plate(self):
            number_plate = self.cleaned_data['number_plate']
            van = Van.objects.filter(number_plate=number_plate).exists()

            if van:
                raise forms.ValidationError("A van with this number plate has been registered.")
            return number_plate
```

**views.py**

```
def edit_van_detail(request, slug):
    van = get_object_or_404(Van, slug=slug)
    van_form = VanForm(instance=van)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        van_form = VanForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=van)
        if van_form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('edit_van_detail', args=(van.slug,)))

    context = {
        'van_form': van_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'van/add_van.html', context)
```

Create is working fine. But on Edit page, when I submit form, it gives unique validation error ("A van with this number plate has been registered.") which I wrote in modelForm. I have done this before without any issue but this time I dont whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation method is wrong. You are checking if any Van have this licence plate. The van you are editing has it...

You should remove the model being currently edited.

```
    def clean_number_plate(self):
        number_plate = self.cleaned_data['number_plate']
        van = Van.objects.filter(number_plate=number_plate).exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).exists()

        if van:
            raise forms.ValidationError("A van with this number plate has been registered.")
```

This will work even when creating a new model. The primary key of non saved model is None.
return number_plate